# PTIJ: Why use a ring network for covering the altar?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Shemot 27:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=444) says that on the net-work that surrounds the *mizbe'ach* (altar), one should place four rings, one one each corner. Thus, one needs to create a [ring network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_network), which is a somewhat common data communication topology.

Why does the altar need a ring network?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

Ring networks have strong advantages for teshuva. See [Ring Network wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_network) where it lists the advantages:

- Point to point line configuration makes it easy to identify and isolate faults.
- Reconfiguration for line faults of bidirectional rings can be very fast, as switching happens at a high level, and thus the traffic does not require individual rerouting.

So on the mizbe'ach, faults are corrected in the optimal way.